# MultiSelect Combo is not coming in Choosen Plugin. Choosen.css is missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

I need a multiselect combobox in html which is as a generaic, mean Which I can use any where. So for that 
I downloaded JQuery Choosen [GitHub Choosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) to my local and wanted to run. In my case Multiselect combo is not comping. see screenshot.

1. How to use this plugin only for Multiselect combo for my dynamic data. I mean I can load from myxml or myJSON by using some url.
2. Is there any way I can achieve same thing in plain javascript.

After removing some code (I kept code only for multiple select)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Chosen: A jQuery Plugin by Harvest to Tame Unwieldy Select Boxes</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="docsupport/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="docsupport/prism.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="chosen.css">

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; style-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:">

</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="content">
      <div class="side-by-side clearfix">
      </div>
        <div class="side-by-side clearfix">
        <div>
          <em>Into This</em>
          <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="United States">United States</option>
            <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
            <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
            <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
            <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="docsupport/prism.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="docsupport/init.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

After investigation I get to knew that choosen.css is missing. How Can I get this.

[image]

Comment: Some code sample would help us to identify the problem.

Comment: @er-han I downloaded the complete project from git.. So I am not sure what Is going wrong. Still I will place index.html in few mins.

Comment: @er-han I updated my Questions.